# find the <time> tag, explode the date inside, then echo it

Tags: php

I am trying to get the date from a `<time>` tag

```
$explode = explode( '<time class="abs">', file_get_contents($url))[1];
$get_date = explode("</time>" , $explode);
echo date_format(date_create($get_date[0]),"Y/m/d");
```

The echo shows the date but there is also an error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
```

When I do a var_dump, it shows that there is nothing in the array but then why does it echo the correct date..?

Comment: bad approach to scrapeing  HTML :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: can't see how this'd issue an `offset: 1`, since you're only accessing offset `0`. Have you tried `var_dump($explode, $get_date)` to see if the explode is working properly?  and technically speaking, you should be using a DOM parser for this.

Comment: of course, you're using `date_create()` wrong. it's `date_create($time_value, $time_zone)`. `Y/m/d` is **NOT** a timezone.

Comment: @MarcB Look the the first code line to the right at the end :) -> `file_get_contents($url))` **[1]**

Comment: @Dagon i just dont want to use any classes that are not my own so this is the only solution i came up with

Comment: is there a way to fix the error? i mean it echo's what i need, just the error message is irritating

Comment: did you write explode? file_get_contents? no? so you already are. DOM is as inbuilt as explode et al

Comment: Depending on your version of PHP using the array accesser directly on the function may be the issue.

Comment: @dagon yeah but I don't have to license anything. I am using the latest PHP version

Comment: first 4 items on the linked post are native php. all 100% better than scrapeing your way

Comment: @Dagon so what should i do? I am not too sure how to use DOMs